# HTML output from PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add one div in the same level as div with class second. Php code:

```
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {

    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    if($depth == 0){
        $out_div = '<div class="second"><div class="inner">';
    }else{
        $out_div = '';
    }

    // build html
    $output .= "\n" . $indent . $out_div  .'<ul>' . "\n";
}
function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);

    if($depth == 0){
        $out_div_close = '</div></div>';
    }else{
        $out_div_close = '';
    }

    $output .= "$indent</ul>". $out_div_close ."\n";
}
```

The problem is that it adds my div but as another level.

Example it goes second>mydiv>inner and I need it to be second mydiv>inner so mydiv is not child of second.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Could you be clearer as to how you called the functions, the output you expect and what you got?

Comment: If you need it to be at the same level as something else, the previous thing needs to end with `</div>`

Comment: yea it was simple, thank you barman. I just open closed the div I need and its on the same level. Post as answer if you want. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Barma you're now a barman 

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is. You haven't shown the code that calls the function.

Comment: <div class="second"><div class"mydiv"></div><div class="inner"> This does the trick. Previously I have closed that mydiv with $out_div_close and that made it go in levels.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/180501/45483